# If-statement in Page{} environment QML

Tags: if-statement, qml

i simply try to decide to display a different page in my QML-Projecet with respect to a certain condition. Right now im doing it like this:

```
Page {
    id: pageMain
    visible: true
    width: 1024
    height: 600

if (condition) {
Page1{}
}
else Page2{}
}
```

But unfortunately this isnt working as expected. How can i solve my problem?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing the syntax of javascript and QML. You probably want to use a Loader like this:

```
Page {
    id: pageMain
    visible: true
    width: 1024
    height: 600

    Component {
        id: page1
        Page1 {}
    }

    Component {
        id: page2
        Page2 {}
    }

    Loader {
        sourceComponent: condition ? page1 : page2
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes you are right. Right now im changing alot between several languages and i mix up stuff.